# how to get int[][] dimensionArray?

Tags: java

I want to get matrix[i][j] to my int[][] gettwodimensionalArray, I try so many way, but when I do the test, my gettwodimensionaArray still not store from matrix[i][j]. Please help me out, thank you.

Here is my code look like.

```
    public int[][] gettwodimensionalArray(String file_name) {
    File file = new File(file_name);
    ArrayList<int[]> rows = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] s = line.split("\\s+");
            int[] row = new int[s.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                row[i] = Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
            }
            rows.add(row);
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int numbOfRow = rows.size();
    // find number of columns by gettting the lenght of one of the rows row

    int keepTrackSizeFirstRow;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbOfRow; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            keepTrackSizeFirstRow = rows.get(0).length;

        }
        // compare current row i's array length, to keetracksizefirstrow
    }

    int[][] matrix = new int[numbOfRow][rows.get(0).length];
    // System.out.println(matrix);

    for (int i = 0; i < numbOfRow; i++) {
        // i = row

        for (int j = 0; j < rows.get(i).length; j++) {
            // j = col

            matrix[i][j] = rows.get(i)[j];
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);

        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: What problems are you having? "still not store from matrix[i][j]" isn't helpful as the code works to an extent, but will not work if the later rows are greater than the prior rows.

Comment: Another helpful tip. your for loop of keepTrackSizeFirstRow = rows.get(0).length; is unnessary, you don't need that to fetch the first item. What you need to do is check if its empty and then if it isn't then you know there is something on the first item rather than doing a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do. If you want each row of the input to fit in the array, you can declare the array with variable sizes, like this:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[numbOfRow][];
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    matrix[i] = new int[rows.get(i).length];
}
```

If instead you want all rows to have the same length, you should find the maximum length of the input like this:

```
int maxlength = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
    maxlength = (rows.get(i).length > maxlength) ? rows.get(i).length : maxlength;
}
int[][] matrix = new int[numbOfRow][maxlength];
```

Comment: Thank you, that would be help a lot.

Comment: My question is in my matrix[i][j] contain integer matrix number, and I want to return it into my getTwodimensionalArray, but I do not know how to do it. I know that it should do with return something to gettwodimensionalArray. I'm very appreciate.

Comment: `return matrix` does exactly that. Since `getTwodimensionalArray()` is declared `int[][]`, it is the correct type. Note that you cannot assign a static size to the return array. It will have the size of the returned object.

Comment: But, when I do System.out.println(matrix), it contain this: [[I@503b7e8[[I@503b7e8[[I@503b7e8[[I@503b7e8[[I@503b7e8[[I@503b7e8[[I@503b7e8[[I@503b7e8[[I@503b7e8.

Comment: My purpose is want to return matrix[i][j] that contain int[][] matrix number, but I do not know how to bring matrix[i][j] outside of for loop.

Comment: @user1997751 To print an array do `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));` You will also have to `import java.util.Arrays;`

Comment: One more question, so "int[][] gettwodimensionalArray" store my int[][] matrix too? if "int[][] gettwodimensionalArray" is not store my int[][] matrix, how do I store them into my "int[][] gettwodimensionalArray"? thank again.

Comment: @user1997751 I am not sure I understand.... you will call it like this `int[][] a; a = gettwodimensionalArray("myfile.txt"); System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));` from another method of the same object. From another object you would do `theObject.gettwodimensionalArray("myfile.txt");` , where `theObject` has been constructed, is the correct class etc. The matrix declared in the method won't be destroyed as long as there is a reference to it.